# calculating ratio of aggregates for subsample satisfying a condition

Tags: sql, case, aggregate-functions, case-when, monetdb

I have annual earnings (`loneink`) for 2007 for each individial ID (`personlopnr`), and I want to calculate for each company ID (`peorglopnr`) how much of the total wage bill was paid to worker born after 1980 (birth year is `fodelsear`), in aggregate. However, the code below produces a `share` column which is 0 for a vast majority of the cases and 1 for the rest. (To be clear, the code with `WHERE loneink > 0` as below produces only 1s — the zero comeback without that condition and having a `NULLIF` to make sure I never divide by zero.) While there are many firms with no young workers, it is clearly not the case that all the other firms are young-only.

What is wrong here? This wasn't the way to generate a "young-wage" variable where for older workers earnings are zero, so the sum is only for the young? Or in theory this is OK, but I got the `CASE WHEN` wrong? Or the `SUM`/`SUM` misbehaves with `GROUP BY`?

What is a better way to do this?

```
CREATE VIEW sys.over26_2007 (personlopnr,peorglopnr,loneink,below26_loneink) AS (
SELECT personlopnr,peorglopnr,loneink, CASE WHEN fodelsear < 1981 THEN 0 ELSE loneink END AS below26_loneink
FROM sys.ds_chocker_lev_lisaindivid_2007 WHERE loneink > 0
);
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM over26_2007;

CREATE VIEW sys.share26_2007 (peorglopnr,share26_2007) AS (
SELECT peorglopnr, SUM(below26_loneink)/SUM(loneink)
FROM sys.over26_2007
WHERE loneink > 0
GROUP BY peorglopnr
);
```

My actual use case is in MonetDB, so hopefully we can stick to SQL:2003 solutions only, no mySQL or Oracle extensions.

Comment: have you tried to list the `SUM(below26_loneink)` and `SUM(loneink)` columns separately? It is maybe a case when the results of `SUM()` need to be casted to decimal type (or whatever it is called in MonetDB) and then divide

Comment: @cha I did check `MIN`,`AVG` and `MAX` for both `loneink` and `below26_loneink` in `over26_2007`. That worked fine. Doesn't it mean that the `SUM` should not be a problem? Or what am I missing?

Comment: what column type is your `loneink`?

Comment: @cha You mean in the view? How do I query that? MonetDB has no information_schema, and I cannot `SELECT over26_2007 FROM tables` as it is a view.

Comment: Never mind... Try this: `CAST(SUM(below26_loneink) AS double) / CAST(SUM(loneink) AS double)`. BTW, when you create the column, in your CASE statement use 0.0, like this: `CASE WHEN fodelsear < 1981 THEN 0.0 ELSE loneink END`

Comment: @cha Thanks, this solved it! I am happy to accept an answer here if you write up something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, when you create the view, you need to use 0.0 in your case statement. This will make sure that the column in the view is created using a correct data type (double in your case):

```
CREATE VIEW sys.over26_2007 (personlopnr,peorglopnr,loneink,below26_loneink) AS (
SELECT personlopnr,peorglopnr,loneink, 
       CASE WHEN fodelsear < 1981 THEN 0.0 ELSE loneink END AS below26_loneink
FROM sys.ds_chocker_lev_lisaindivid_2007 WHERE loneink > 0.0
);
```

Next, in your other view, CAST the sum to double as well:

```
CREATE VIEW sys.share26_2007 (peorglopnr,share26_2007) AS (
SELECT peorglopnr, CAST(SUM(below26_loneink) AS double) / CAST(SUM(loneink) AS double)
FROM sys.over26_2007
WHERE loneink > 0
GROUP BY peorglopnr
);
```